# What happen play gta online on ps3 with ps4 acc

Tags: ps3, ps4, grand-theft-auto-online

What happen play gta online on ps3 with ps4 account?
It create new charecter? Or load my ps4 character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save data isn't stored on Rockstar servers and GTAV does not have cross platform support. This means your PS4 will have no record of your PS3 character, requiring you to start with a new character at level 1 to go online.